# Moving Sharepoint site/Content DB

Tags: 2013, site-collection

I've got a question regarding moving a sharepoint site.

Basically a user has created a Site collection on a wrong content DB and I'm now having to move it.

The problem I have is that content on the old content DB needs to be moved with the site but not all of it.

The site has a wiki list of pages and I need to get that from the old content db to the new one.

What would be the best method to do this? Would I be best off just backing up the list and importing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PowerShell Cmdlet [Move-SPSite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607915.aspx) to move a Site Collection from one Content Database to another.

BUT there is NO way to move a part of as Site Collection to another Content database. ALL of a site collection is ALWAYS stored in ONE and only ONE Content Database.

A farm has one or more Web Applications
A Web Application has one or more Content Databases
A Content Database has one or more Site Collections
A Site Collection as one or more Sites
A Site has zero or more lists
...

Answer (score 2):

If you just need that list from the old contentdb / site collection, just create a new Site Collection where you want the data to be, export the list from the old location and import it at the new location

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx

If you do not need the entire site collection, dont move it.